# Is there a way to flip the order of observations in Stata?

Tags: stata

Is it possible to create a backwards counting variable in Stata (like the command _n, just numbering observations backwards)? Or a command to flip the data set, so that the observation with the most recent date is the first one? I would like to make a scatter plot with AfD on the y-axis and the date (row_id) on the x-axis. When I make the plot however, the weeks are ordered backwards. How can I change the order?

This is the code:

```
generate row_id=_n
twoway scatter AfD row_id || lfit AfD row_id
```

Here are the data set and the plot:
[image: Data set]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your problem, plotting in terms of a daily date variable and -- if for some reason that is a good idea -- using `xscale(reverse)` are likely to be what you need, as well explained by @Wouter.

In general something like

```
gen long newid = _N - _n + 1 
sort newid
```

will reverse a dataset.

Comment: Kind of you to accept this, but my answer is just supplementary to that of @Wouter. Feel free to give him the +15 reputation. I've got all the privileges I need or want!

Answer (score 2):

Your date variable is a string variable, which is unlikely to get you the desired result if you sort on that variable.

You can create a Stata internal form date variable from your string variable:

```
gen date_num = daily(date, "MDY")
format date_num %td
```

The values of this new variable will represent the number of days since 1 Jan 1960.

If you create a scatter plot with this date variable on the x-axis, by default it will be sorted from min to max. To let it run from max to min you can specify option `xscale(reverse)`.

If you still want to create an id variable by yourself you can choose one of these options (ascending and descending):

```
sort date_num
gen id = _n

gsort -date_num
gen id = _n
```